# What does transparent mean in“null-terminated transparent array of elements”

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, stdstring

The snapshot is part of the source code of class `basic_string`. What does transparent mean in the following comment. In my opinion, the word transparent is redundant and can be got rid of. Am I right?
[image]
The system on my computer is Visual Studio 2010 RTMRel.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the term "transparent" here refers to the fact that the interface of the `std::basic_string` type manages an array that is directly accessible to the client. A string is *logically* an array of elements, meaning that it functions *as though* it's an array of characters, and specifically the `std::basic_string` type stores the characters in an *actual* array of characters. The client can do pointer arithmetic on the addresses of the individual characters in the string and it's guaranteed to work properly, for example.

Contrast this with, say, `std::deque`, which is *logically* an array but in practice might not *actually* be implemented as an array. A client who wants to work with `std::deque` can't safely get raw addresses of the elements of the `std::deque` and do pointer arithmetic with them in a way that would be guaranteed to work out correctly.